# How to check model data print in controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$data['records'] = $this->front_model->checksettings();
```

I have this scenario the result is below:

```
Array
(
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [setting_status] => 0
                )
        )

)
```

Now I want to apply the `if else` condition here on the basis of `setting_status`. How I can save the `setting_status` value in one variable?

I know only `print_r` shows its value but does not save the value in one variable.

Comment: Try `$data['records']['records'][0]->setting_status` or `$data['records'][0]->setting_status` (I am not sure what are you printing $data or $data['records']).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model instead of `result()` use `row()` to get only one row. Then you will be able to get setting status like this:

```
$status = $data['records']->setting_status;
```

You can also retrieve data as array: instead `row()` use `row_array()`.

Comment: Thanks brother Muhammadhzp